# What is hunter's chicken

Tags: chicken

My long held opinion of this was that Hunter's Chicken was chicken breast, stuffed with cheese, wrapped in bacon and, occasionally, with barbecue sauce over the top.  Recipes like [these](http://studentrecipes.com/recipes/chicken/chicken-wrapped-in-bacon/) seem to agree with me.

However, I've just been looking around the web to see if I could get a recipe with any new ideas, and came across [this](http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/chicken-recipes/hunter-s-chicken-stew-pollo-alla-cacciatora/#Cid8wW0bA2VeRusg.97).  There's a few others in the same vein, which basically have it as a chicken stew.

So, which is correct?  Or are they both?

Comment: The first one you linked didn't call it hunter's chicken - only a single commenter mentioned that name.

Comment: The first one was to give an illustration of my understanding.

Comment: @Johanna is definitely right, there is no set standard. When I think hunter's <insert dish here> I think simple, the kind of thing a hunter might rustle up in the woods or a basic hunting lodge. I'd be inclined to go with the stew in this case as there's nothing simple about stuffing with cheese and wrapping with bacon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of different dishes, and not enough names, and different parts of the world don't agree with each other on what things should be called. In general, there is no standard for what a dish a certain name corresponds to. I believe for example Italy has standardized some recipes, but there are still people making their own version of that dish, and calling it by the same name. To summarize, both are correct. There is no universal body that names dishes.